# errors while runing makefile with cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

i have ran this makefile in cygwin and i got some errors this is makefile:

```
FFLAGS=
BFLAGS=-d -v -y 
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings -I /usr/local/boost_1_50_0

FLEX=flex
BISON=bison
CC=g++

SRCS=y.tab.c ast.cpp tokentable.cpp symboltable.cpp main.cpp lex.yy.c      semanticanalyzer.cpp astnodevisitor.cpp constants.cpp astnodetypechecker.cpp utility.cpp  astnodecodegenerator.cpp
OBJS=y.tab.o ast.o tokentable.o symboltable.o main.o lex.yy.o semanticanalyzer.o  astnodevisitor.o constants.o astnodetypechecker.o utility.o astnodecodegenerator.o

cooc : ${OBJS} 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${OBJS}

%.o : %.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<

y.tab.c : cool.y
    ${BISON} ${BFLAGS} cool.y

lex.yy.c : cool.flex
    ${FLEX} ${FFLAGS} cool.flex

.depend: ${SRCS} 
    rm -f ./.depend
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -MM $^>>./.depend

include .depend
```

and i got this errors:

MAKE Version 5.0  Copyright (c) 1987, 1997 Borland International
Error makefile 25: Colon expected
Error makefile 26: Command syntax error
Error makefile 27: Command syntax error
Error makefile 29: Command syntax error
*** 4 errors during make ***

Answer (score 0):

This is a GNU make makefile.  You are running Windows `nmake`.  Those two programs are not compatible.  If you're using cygwin, install the GNU make program for cygwin and use that instead.

Comment: I have install MinGW and msys too can i use them for running this makefile?

Comment: If you install GNU make built for this yes you can.  You should not use GNU make built for MinGW when trying to build inside cygwin, and you should not use GNU make built for cygwin when trying to build outside if cygwin.

Comment: i have download make-4.0 but i can not understand how to use it